# The convergence of complex numbers is equivalent to the convergence of absolute values and arguments

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> The statement $z_n \to z_0 \neq 0$ is equivalent to
>   $$
>  \lim_{n \to \infty} |z_n| = |z_0|
>  \quad\text{and}\quad
>  \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{Arg} \ z_n = \mathrm{Arg} \ z_0.
> $$

I want to prove the above statement , where $z$ is a complex number and $\mathrm{Arg}$ is the principal argument of $z$.

I used the definition of limit and triangle inequality than I can get the first part.

For the second part, from what I know, $\mathrm{Arg} \ z$ is depend on which quadrant that the complex number lies on and for quadrant 1,4 it is Argz=arctan(y/x),for 2 it is arctan(y/x)+pi,for 3 it is arctan(y/x) -pi . I don’t know how to do the calculation when I try to prove this by using definition of limit.

Comment: How is $\mathrm{Arg} \  z$ acutally defined? In partilcular, what is the domain of $\mathrm{Arg}$? If we try to define an argument on the whole of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ then this statement is false.

Comment: for quadrant 1,4 Argz=arctan(y/x),for 2 it is arctan(y/x)+pi,for 3 it is arctan(y/x) -pi

Comment: if $f$ is injective, then $\lim x_n = l$ is equivalent to $\lim f(x_n) = f(l)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214301/convergence-of-the-arguments-of-a-sequence-of-complex-numbers?lq=1 i think i can use the above question to ask this question because they are approximately the same, is it correct?

Comment: can any one give me some hint on how to prove the argument part

Comment: By your definiton $\mathrm{Arg}$ is not defined on the real line (I assume that $x$ and $y$ denote the real and imaginary part respectively.) So what is $\mathrm{Arg} \ x$ supposed to be for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true: $$z_n = -1 + \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\,i$$ clearly converges to $-1$, but $\operatorname{Arg}(z_n) \approx \pi$ for even $n$ and $\approx -\pi$ for odd $n$.

(The implication in the other direction is valid though.)

Comment: If Arg z only take from -pi/2 to pi/2, then the claim will be true? anyway thank you for your help